# "Value" causing issues in schema generation

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

I have an object like this:

```
"Meta": {
    "Type": 10,
    "Key": "Meta",
    "Value": {     <================ This is the "Value" in question
        "ElementType": {
            "Type": 2,
            "Key": "ElementType",
            "Value": "P"
        },
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": 9,
            "Key": "Attributes",
            "Value": [{
                "Type": 2,
                "Key": "ID",
                "Value": "cat"
            },
            {
                "Type": 2,
                "Key": "Class",
                "Value": ""
            }],
            "ContentType": 2
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to generate an Avro schema out of this, it throws an error.  **If I change the first instance of "Value" to a purposeful typo (I used "Valuz"), then the schema parses fine.**

This is the object (with "Valuz" substituted in)

```
"Meta": {
    "Type": 10,
    "Key": "Meta",
    "Valuz": {     <================ Note this substitution
        "ElementType": {
            "Type": 2,
            "Key": "ElementType",
            "Value": "P"
        },
        "Attributes": {
            "Type": 9,
            "Key": "Attributes",
            "Value": [{
                "Type": 2,
                "Key": "ID",
                "Value": "cat"
            },
            {
                "Type": 2,
                "Key": "Class",
                "Value": ""
            }],
            "ContentType": 2
        }
    }
}
```

This is the schema (with "Valuz" substituted in)

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "MyClass",
    "namespace": "com.test.avro",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "Meta",
        "type": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "Meta",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "Type",
                "type": "long"
            },
            {
                "name": "Key",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "Valuz",     <================ This is the "Value" with the typo substitution working fine
                "type": {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "Valuz",     <================ This is the "Value" with the typo substitution working fine
                    "fields": [{
                        "name": "ElementType",
                        "type": {
                            "type": "record",
                            "name": "ElementType",
                            "fields": [{
                                "name": "Type",
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Key",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Value",
                                "type": "string"
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Attributes",
                        "type": {
                            "type": "record",
                            "name": "Attributes",
                            "fields": [{
                                "name": "Type",
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Key",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Value",
                                "type": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "record",
                                        "name": "Value",
                                        "fields": [{
                                            "name": "Type",
                                            "type": "long"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Key",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Value",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "ContentType",
                                "type": "long"
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

My question is simply, what is it about "Value" in this context that is causing the Avro schema to fail?  **As per the error below, it says that it cannot redefine "Value", but where is it being defined in the first place?**

For reference, I attempted this in Apache NiFi and it just says that it can't parse the schema.  I found this website [Avro schema to JSON Schema](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/avro.jsp) that quotes this error, which seems to give more insight into the issue:

```
[ {
  "level" : "fatal",
  "message" : "illegal Avro schema",
  "exceptionClass" : "org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException",
  "exceptionMessage" : "Can't redefine: com.test.avro.Value",
  "info" : "other messages follow (if any)"
} ]
```

Comment: you should provide some information about how you are parsing the schema and the full stack, that schema does not seem to be valid for me ./